# How to define absolute path of xml, images folder and main swf path in this swf object code?

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, xhtml, swfobject

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("loader.swf", "flash-banner", "920", "320", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
```

After loading `loader.swf` I'm getting this error `Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.`

This is folder structure.

```
loader.swf
main.swf
main.xml
images
  1.jpg
  2.jpg
  3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Flash error. It happens when a `Loader` instance fails to find the file it was attempting to load.

One possible cause is that the *other* file(s) needed are not in the same folder as the main file (loader.swf).

Comment: all are in same folder but i'm in a CMS where every file is a  object.

Comment: In this case, you have to use the absolute path to the file, it might be something like: /Library/Files/mydata.xml
This is that one that you should use inside flash. You can know the path by using firebug (Net tab)

Comment: Yes this is my question where and how to set absolute path in this swf object code.

Comment: I depends on how this loader is coded. Mostly, you have to change the path somewhere inside Flash, not in the HTML embed code.